# Multiple mat-select does not display the correct value

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a multi-select dropdown with an option to select all the options.
The code works perfectly fine but once you select All and then deselect one of the options,All is still displayed,though it works perfectly functionality wise.

I have tried updating value and validity of the form factoring in maybe the rendering issues
[image: It should not be displaying all]

I have code similar to the following [stackblitz-demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-with-angular-v5-jsgvx6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of formcontrol is not getting updated and if you would check the value of your controls you will find 0 which is value of "All"
You need to splice this value and patch the correct value to your formcontrol.